# Error:(140) No resource identifier found for attribute 'resizableActivity' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have changed api level to 24 in my build.gradle
but I still getting error: **Error:(140) No resource identifier found for attribute 'resizableActivity' in package 'android'**

```
compileSdkVersion 'Device manufacturers:Device Manufacturers MDM Addon:24'
buildToolsVersion "24"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 24
```

Comment: Change `compileSdkVersion 'Device manufacturers:Device Manufacturers MDM Addon:24'` to `compileSdkVersion 24`, in this project or some other scrap project that you create that uses `resizableActivity`. If the problem goes away, you need to ask whoever gave you `Device manufacturers:Device Manufacturers MDM Addon` how to fix your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare I changed to compileSdkVersion 24, but it still shows Error:(140) No resource identifier found for attribute 'resizableActivity' in package 'android'

Comment: Note that there is an `e`: `android:resizeableActivity`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, it worked with compileSdkVersion 24, but still failed at 'Device manufacturers:Device Manufacturers MDM Addon:24'

Comment: Then you have to talk to that device manufacturer.